# Is it possible to upload a file into the server only with client side scripting using HTML,CSS and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to upload a file in  my server for personal use . I have done the downloading part but
cannot figure out how to upload without using any server side scripting.!!!!!!1

I have found the solution using server side scripting. But i need to do with plain js or  any other client side scripting!

Comment: You wouldn't be happy if an arbitrary web page could save any files anywhere on your server without asking your permission.

Comment: If the server already has a mechanism or solution where you can upload files, then it may be possible to use that mechanism/solution via JS (i.e. you don't need to write your own code). In other words: You WILL need some script/service/mechanism on the server side that receives your file and saves it. You cannot "just send a file". It must be received and managed on the server side.

Comment: I need it for my personal use !

Answer (score 0):

No. To upload something to the server, the server must provide a mechanism to receive the upload.